# When I try to send intent to activity was being displayed using app link, new activity is created

Tags: android, android-activity, viewmodel, applinks, android-savedstate

My app implements OAuth 2.0 using a custom tab and **App Link**, and obtains data sent with a redirect URL through App Link through `onNewIntent()`.
I'm trying to send a method to send this data to the `ViewModel` of the `Activity` along with some data that is sent when displaying this `Activity` to the server side along with some data stored using `SavedStateHandle`.
According to my Firebase Crashlytics and customer reports, depending on device, `onNewIntent()` isn't called, but `onCreate()`, where a new activity is created, is called.
However, at this time, the data stored in `SavedStateHandle` doesn't exist, and since it was not created with `putExtra()`, there is no data and a `NullPointException` occurs.
I think this is an impossible case based on my knowledge because there are additional settings as shown below, but can I know why a new `Activity` is created like this?

1. The launch mode uses singleTask.
2. When displaying an activity, the flag is not set separately.
3. Multi module is used and compose is not used.
4. We added processing to disable the do not preserve activity mode, so if that happens, the activity will not be reached.
5. It is used Kotlin, and the Activity lib version is **1.4.0** and the Lifecycle version is **2.4.1**.
6. This occurs regardless of OS version and device brand.

Comment: Sounds like Android is killing your `Activity` when you launch the browser to process the authentication, so that when OAuth returns to your app, Android needs to create a new OS Process for your app and relaunch your `Activity`. You will need to be able to support this situation as Android can kill your app once it goes to the background.

Comment: @DavidWasser Is this possible that the activity of the app behind it may be killed while the Chrome custom tab is running?

Comment: Absolutely! On a low-resource device, Android can and will kill off any resource-intensive apps that are no longer visible. You can see this especially when launching a camera app from another app to take a photo or video.

Comment: @DavidWasser
Oh, Thank you for answer!  
So, is there a solution to prevent the activity from being launched in a new task or that activity is existing already in the task from being terminated?  
What do you think about using `singleInstance` launch mode?

Comment: You can't prevent android from killing your app in these cases. You'll need to architect your app so that you can recover from this. The best scenario is to store some information in `SharedPreferences` when you launch the Chrome Custom tab. When Android returns to your app, you need to check if your process has been killed and recreated (you can use a `static boolean` variable to remember and verify that). If it has been recreated, you'll need to restore the important data from `SharedPreferences` before you continue processing.

Comment: A special launch mode won't help you in this situation.

Comment: Oh, that's really the way to use `SharedPreferences`... thank you sir!

Comment: If you've been able to solve your problem, you should create an answer to your own question and accept that answer. That may help others with a similar problem and also will get this question off the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I solved it like this.

1. **Separate the activity** that runs the chrome custom tab and the activity for App Link.
2. Add the following flag to the intent of the custom tab.

```
.intent.apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
}
```

3. Set the launch mode of the App Link activity to `singleTop`.
4. Before running the chrome custom tab in the activity that runs the chrome custom tab, save the data needed by the activity for App Link as SharedPrefrences.
5. After retrieving data from SharedPreferences in the App Link activity, reset the data in SharedPreferences.
   (For reference, I used EncryptedSharedPreferences.)